# How to Merge Data Sets After Filtering Out Certain Text?

Tags: node.js, express

Using Nodejs, Express, Neo4j data and API data

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, please point me in that direction.

On my server.js file, I have a set of Neo4j data: **dbtabArr**

```
[ { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleOne' },
  { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleTwo' },
  { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleThree' }]
```

And another set of API data: **wikiArr**

```
[ { id: 'abc123',
title: 'tabTitleOne TextIDontWant'},
  { id: 'def456',
title: 'tabTitleThree TextIDontWant'}]
```

**NOTE that there is NO 'title: tabTitleTwo' in this wikiArr, sometimes there will not be a 1:1 counterpart in the dbtabArr.**

I want to join the datasets and I understand I could do something like

```
const obj1 = dbtabArr;
const obj2 = wikiArr;
 
const mergedObject = {
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2
};
```

But that would just put the top data over the bottom data.

Ultimately, I would like the new data set to look like this: **newDataArr**

```
[ { id: 'abc123',
    dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleOne' },
  { id: NULL,
    dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleTwo' },
{ id: 'def456',
    dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitleThree' }]
```

The only possible join attribute is the **tabTitle** & **title** properties seen in both Arrs, but the one title property has **TextI DontWant**.
And I am hoping to have the tabTitle: 'tabTitleTwo' with the id: NULL available in the new data set as that will show where any gaps are when rendered on my ejs page.

**Here's what I've tried so far**
To remove the unwanted text:

```
var wikiArr2= wikiArr.map(function(v) {
        return v.toString().replace(/ TextI DontWant/g, '');
      });
```

To merge the 2 arrays:

```
      const map = new Map();
      tabTitleArr.forEach(item => map.set(item.tabTitle, item));
      wikiArr2.forEach(item => map.set(item.title, {...map.get(item.title), ...item}));
      const mergedArr = Array.from(map.values());
```

The result is not what I was hoping for (using real returned data, the top object of the array is from dbtabArr and the bottom object (spelling out object) is from wikiArr):

```
[ { dbSpecId: Integer { low: 1234567, high: 0 },
    dbTitle: 'dbTitle',
    tabTitle: 'tabTitle' },
  { '0': '[',
    '1': 'o',
    '2': 'b',
    '3': 'j',
    '4': 'e',
    '5': 'c',
    '6': 't',
    '7': ' ',
    '8': 'O',
    '9': 'b',
    '10': 'j',
    '11': 'e',
    '12': 'c',
    '13': 't',
    '14': ']' } ]
```

......

The items I seem to need help with are:

1. How can I filter out the text I don't want from the title in data set wikiArr, whether before or after data is rendered?
2. How do I do what I am assuming is an If Else to match or compare the titles from the first and second data sets (or other comparison?)
3. Is there a better way to merge the 2 data sets into the 1 than using ... spread?

Apologies for the list, happy to parse out to separate items.

Many Thanks!

Comment: updated question with what I've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having assumed that `wikiArr.title` starts with `dbtabArr.tabTitle`,  I've generated the `newDataArr` this way:

```js
const dbtabArr = [
  { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne', tabTitle: 'tabTitleOne' },
  { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne', tabTitle: 'tabTitleTwo' },
  { dbTitle: 'dbTitleOne', tabTitle: 'tabTitleThree' },
];
const wikiArr = [
  { id: 'abc123', title: 'tabTitleOne TextIDontWant' },
  { id: 'def456', title: 'tabTitleThree TextIDontWant' },
];

const newDataArr = dbtabArr
.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const [wiki] = wikiArr.filter(w => w.title.startsWith(x.tabTitle));
  // const id = wiki?.id ?? null; // Nodejs 16+
  const id = wiki && wiki.id ? wiki.id : null;
  return [...acc, { id, ...x }];
}, []);

console.log(newDataArr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr. R, unfortunately my server won't even start, citing the error of **const id = wiki?.id ?? null;** = "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I've fixed the backward compatibility issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator